# Google Sheets: Return best matching text string from a column of text strings

Tags: regex, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, substitution

Let's say we have the name "Giorge", I'm looking for a way to return the best matching name from the table of names below:

| Names |
| --- |
| George |
| Patrick |
| Charles |

Comment: Do a search for the first letter?  then first two letters or 3? Or a fuzzy search? Have you considered wildcards? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SORTN(A2:A4, 1, 1, LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A4, "["&B2&"]", )), 1)
```

[image]